# Value error when called printing function in pairs in Python Chatbot

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I am working on chatbot.But while use function links in pairs, some errors occured.I want to print subjects in list.And after user can choose the subject which is desired.But while printing subjects, there is some problem which i could't solve.

```
from nltk.chat.util import Chat, reflections
from tkinter import *
import re
import numpy as np

subjectAreaList = ["subject1","subjec2","subject3"]

    
def listSubjectArea():
    i = 1
    for a in subjectAreaList:
        print(i,". ",a)
        i = i + 1
        
        
pairs = [
    ['i want to see reports', ['In which subject area would you like to see the reports?'],listSubjectArea()],
    ['subject1(.*)', ['blah blah blah']],
    ['subject2(.*)', ['blah blah blah']],
    ['subject3(.*)', ['blah blah blah']]
]

reflections = {
    'i am' : 'you are',
    'i was' : 'you were',
    'i': 'you'
}



chat = Chat(pairs, reflections)
print("Hi,What do you want to do ?")
chat.converse(quit='by')
```

But I got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Projects/demo.py", line 71, in <module>
    chat = Chat(pairs, reflections)
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\chat\util.py", line 52, in __init__
    self._pairs = [(re.compile(x, re.IGNORECASE), y) for (x, y) in pairs]
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\chat\util.py", line 52, in <listcomp>
    self._pairs = [(re.compile(x, re.IGNORECASE), y) for (x, y) in pairs]
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I can not find why is that error return. I check my loop but nothing change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because the pair list has in the first index 3 items and the `[(re.compile(x, re.IGNORECASE), y) for (x, y) in pairs]`  statement expect to 2 items. 
So you can try

```
 pairs = [
    ['i want to see reports', [['In which subject area would you like to see the reports?'],listSubjectArea()]],
    ['subject1(.*)', ['blah blah blah']],
    ['subject2(.*)', ['blah blah blah']],
    ['subject3(.*)', ['blah blah blah']]
]
```

OR

```
pairs = [
    ['i want to see reports', ['In which subject area would you like to see the reports?',listSubjectArea()]],
    ['subject1(.*)', ['blah blah blah']],
    ['subject2(.*)', ['blah blah blah']],
    ['subject3(.*)', ['blah blah blah']]
]
```

Comment: I solve the problem but  when I use like this,all functions in pairs list automatically called at the beginning.I would like to call functions, when they called by related pair.Do you have any idea about that ?

Comment: I'm not sure it's probably something in the `from nltk.chat.util import Chat` class you need to check how it treats function init.

Answer (score 0):

For example, I have a problem;

as you all know this is the basic code (abbreviated of course):

```
from nltk.chat.util import Chat, reflections


pairs = (
    (
        r"I need (.*)",
        (
            "Why do you need %1?",
            "Would it really help you to get %1?",
            "Are you sure you need %1?",
        ),
    ),
    (
        r"Why don\'t you (.*)",
        (
            "Do you really think I don't %1?",
            "Perhaps eventually I will %1.",
            "Do you really want me to %1?",
        ),
    )
)

    
reflections = {
    "i am": "you are",
    "i was": "you were",
    "i": "you",
    "i'm": "you are"
}




def chatty():
    print("Hi, how are you?") #default message at the start
    chat = Chat(pairs, reflections)
    chat.converse()
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    chatty()
```

We want to organize the code as follows. When a question that we have determined is asked, it takes an action. For example, make a search on a site or something like that.

```
from nltk.chat.util import Chat, reflections
from googlesearch import search


gs=search(Chat)


pairs = (
    (
        r"I need (.*)",
        (
            "Why do you need %1?",
            "Would it really help you to get %1?",
            ((gs)+"%1?"),
        ),
    ),
    (
        r"Why don\'t you (.*)",
        (
            "Do you really think I don't %1?",
            "Perhaps eventually I will %1.",
            "Do you really want me to %1?",
        ),
    )
)

    
reflections = {
    "i am": "you are",
    "i was": "you were",
    "i": "you",
    "i'm": "you are"
}





def chatty():
    print("Hi, how are you?")
    chat = Chat(pairs, reflections)
    chat.converse()
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    chatty()
```

We actually want this. to be able to interfere with chat.converse()

Comment: This is not an answer to the question but a **question** as itself, if you have any questions about the topic please post a *question* with the appropriate tags.